Magento 2 | Default shipping address not selected on checkout
When I access checkout shipping step, my default shipping address is preselected, right after page is successfully loaded, then there is additional reload of shipping methods (loader is shown) and my selected shipping address became unselected. There is no more selected shipping address.
If I reload the page again then it will remain selected because there is no more that additional reload of shipping methods.
Why this additional reload of shipping methods happens and unselects my selected shipping address?

Have you use third party extension for shipping methods or billing sections? Then try to disable and check issue still there or not.
